# IOS AppStore - Simple application with webview only

Tags: ios, app-store

We have a responsive site. We would like to make a very simple iOS app which will only load our responsive site url into a WebView component.

i assume that apple will not be ok with that kind of applications. So i am wondering what in the minimal developments i should do so they will consider it as a legitimate app. (Of course that our responsive site is legitimate).

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, and if you do some simple searching you'll find hundreds of discussions about it. I'll offer a quick comment however. Instead of asking *"what will Apple allow"* ask yourself ***"what can I add to the app to make it worthwhile (legitimate) as an app?"*** If you can't come up with anything, then there's no point in making it "an app."

Comment: There is no point asking _us now_ what _Apple_ will do _in the future_. You're asking us to guess about Apple and about the future. Those are both unknowable, especially the Apple part.

Comment: @Omtechguy kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a website & if you are planning to load your site using Webview component that will not be a good option.

Apple will not allow this type applications as this creates Bad user experience. As Webview is only used in some read-only content showing or in some cases there will be Payment Integrations where its used.

**Better Available Option :**

- You must go for the Storyboard based Application which will be more user friendly with creating Mobile Supported APIs to load same content of website into Mobile Application with same look & feel but with a more user friendly look.

Hope this will helps everyone.